# Large height map interpolation

Tags: c++, math

I have a `vector<vector<double>> heightmap` that is dynamically loaded from a CSV file of GPS data to be around 4000x4000. However, only provides 140,799 points.

It produces a greyscale map as shown bellow:
[image]

I wish to interpolate the heights between all the points to generate a height map of the area.

The below code finds all known points will look in a 10m radius of the point to find any other known points. If another point is found then it will linearly interpolate between the 2 points. Interpolated points are defined by - height and unset values are defined as -1337.

This approach is incredibly slow I am sure there are better ways to achieve this.

```
bool run_interp = true;

bool interp_interp = false;

int counter = 0;

while (run_interp)
{
    for (auto x = 0; x < map.size(); x++)
    {
        for (auto y = 0; y < map.at(x).size(); y++)
        {
            const auto height = map.at(x).at(y);

            if (height == -1337) continue;

            if (!interp_interp && height < 0) continue;

            //Look in a 10m radius of a known value to see if there
            //Is another known value to linearly interp between
            //Set height to a negative if it has been interped

            const int radius = (1 / resolution) * 10;

            for (auto rxi = 0; rxi < radius * 2; rxi++)
            {
                //since we want to expand outwards
                const int rx = x + ((rxi % 2 == 0) ? rxi / 2 : -(rxi - 1) / 2);

                if (rx < 0 || rx >= map.size()) continue;

                for (auto ryi = 0; ryi < radius * 2; ryi++)
                {
                    const int ry = y + ((rxi % 2 == 0) ? rxi / 2 : -(rxi - 1) / 2);

                    if (ry < 0 || ry >= map.at(x).size()) continue;

                    const auto new_height = map.at(rx).at(ry);

                    if (new_height == -1337) continue;

                    //First go around we don't want to interp
                    //Interps
                    if (!interp_interp && new_height < 0) continue;

                    //We have found a known point within 10m
                    const auto delta = new_height - height;
                    const auto distance = sqrt((rx- x) * (rx - x)
                        + (ry - y) * (ry - y));
                    const auto angle = atan2(ry - y, rx - x);
                    const auto ratio = delta / distance;

                    //Backtrack from found point until we get to know point
                    for (auto radi = 0; radi < distance; radi++)
                    {
                        const auto new_x = static_cast<int>(x + radi * cos(angle));
                        const auto new_y = static_cast<int>(y + radi * sin(angle));

                        if (new_x < 0 || new_x >= map.size()) continue;
                        if (new_y < 0 || new_y >= map.at(new_x).size()) continue;

                        const auto interp_height = map.at(new_x).at(new_y);

                        //If it is a known height don't interp it
                        if (interp_height > 0)
                            continue;

                        counter++;

                        set_height(new_x, new_y, -interp_height);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << x << " " << counter << std::endl;;

    }

    if (interp_interp)
        run_interp = false;

    interp_interp = true;

}



set_height(const int x, const int y, const double height)
{
//First time data being set
if (map.at(x).at(y) == -1337)
{
    map.at(x).at(y) = height;
}
else // Data set already so average it
{
    //While this isn't technically correct and weights
    //Later data significantly more favourablily
    //It should be fine
    //TODO: fix it.
    map.at(x).at(y) += height;
    map.at(x).at(y) /= 2;
}

}
```

Comment: Do have have any idea what the edge of the map values should be?  Otherwise, there is no way to expand outward towards an edge reliabily.  Perhaps try starting at a known point on the left, then keep scanning to the right until you find another point.  Then linear interpolate along the whole line.  That should be O(n) for points that can be found.  You might try doing the same thing vertically as well to fill in gaps, but again, without outside points, it will be way off.  Hmm - actually, that won't work well.  It needs to be scanned towards the nearest point between gradiant lines.

Comment: Funny: this corrresponds to the first serious programming project I had to implement during my studies, in 1979! We were asked to implement a triangulation of the points with known height and then to perform interpolation inside the triangles. I don't know if it would be faster than your method, but it is very likely that quality of the interpolation will be better. No, I don't kept the programme (fortran77). I am convinced this is still an usual way to perform this job.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the points into a kd-tree, it will be much faster to find the closest point (O(nlogn)).

I'm not sure that will solve all your issues, but it is a start.